# How can I allign the top of two SVG's next to another?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I have two SVG's, one with height: 1250px and width: 700px. And one with height:750px and width:750px. When I put these into my HTML, they are next to each other, just like I want them. The only problem is, the bottoms are alligned with each other.

So above my second SVG there is this 'gap'of nothing. How can I allign the tops of these SVG's so my second SVG is displayed at the top of the page, just like the first one.

I've tried switching the two around, but that didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: vertical-align-top should do as SVG are displayed as inline-block element

Comment: I have tried this, but this displays the second SVG below the first.

Comment: what about white-space:nowrap to keep both on one line ?

Comment: @GCyrillus I uses block to get the second SVG below the first. When I use inline-block, the result is the same as before: the second is alligned at the bottom of the first.

Comment: white-sapce nowrap also produces no result :( They are on one line, the allignment just isn't right

Comment: @GCyrillus I found my problem :) I'm using d3js to create these SVG's and their elements and I used vertical-align the wrong way... But it works now! Thanks GCyrillus!

Comment: If you want you can post this as an answer and I'll accept it ;)

Comment: I added a short answer, other option would be to delete the question too since it doesn't bring much info to the community :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the  `vertical-align`  of your `SVG` elements to `top`.

You may need `white-space:nowrap;` on parent to keep them both on same lime.